# Attach string to each line of Sys.command output

Tags: ocaml

During execution of 2 jobs simultaneously in one terminal using Async library it would be nice to distinguish which message comes from which job.
Is there a way to attach a manual string at the beginning of each line of output from Sys.command during execution of a third-party application?
For example:
job1: message1
job1: message2
job2: message1
I've seen example of redirecting output with Unix.open_process_in, however, will it work together with Async?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which part of your setup is third-party. If you have control over the command lines, and you're running on some kind of Unix-like system, you can get a rough approximation of what you want by just sending output through sed:

```
job1-command 2>&1 | sed -u 's/^/Job 1: /'
```

From the unix command line it looks like this:

```
$ date 2>&1 | sed -u 's/^/Job 1: /'
Job 1: Thu Jul  7 18:54:04 PDT 2016
$ date erroneous 2>&1 | sed -u 's/^/Job 1: /'
Job 1: date: illegal time format
```

The `-u` flag makes the output more responsive (it turns off buffering). On some systems (like OS X) the `-l` flag does this instead.

If you want to separate the standard output from the standard error, things will get more complicated.

This might be too crude for what you want, but I hope it's helpful.